# TFS smart build

Tags: tfs, build

I've made some tfs builds that are run manually.
I know that I can made them launching on specific date/time, on each checkin, ... etc.

Is there any way to auto launch them when a specific file is changed ( example : a configuration file )

Comment: which version TFS are you using? on cloud / on premise?

Comment: TFS 2012, my own servers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box mechanism, but you can achieve a similar result using two build definitions.

The first build definition is a CI that monitors the exact files you are interested in. This is controlled by the workspace. This build does nothing but queuing the second build (you can use the [TFSBuild start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742.aspx) command).

Comment: it'd be a CI build where you cloak everything in your WS but the folders that contain your files?